# TSQL: Filter Data Until Certain Value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, filter

I'm trying to filter this table to show everything up until 'Connect'. This seems so easy but I am having trouble coming up with a simple way to do this. This is just one ID. The 'Connect' can be in different places for each Call ID. Inbound is always first.

```
ID Date      Log      Call ID
-----------------------------
1  12:00 PM  Inbound  12345
2  12:00 PM  Ring     12345
3  12:01 PM  Answer   12345
4  12:04 PM  Trans    12345
5  12:05 PM  Connect  12345
6  12:06 PM  Trans    12345
7  12:30 PM  Term     12345
8  12:30 PM  End      12345
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Calls
WHERE call_ID = /*Some Call_id*/
  AND /*Log is from Inbound to Connect*/
```

Desired output:

```
ID Date      Log      Call ID
-------------------------------
1  12:00 PM  Inbound  12345
2  12:00 PM  Ring     12345
3  12:01 PM  Answer   12345
4  12:04 PM  Trans    12345
5  12:05 PM  Connect  12345
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select c.*
from calls c
where c.id <= (select min(c2.id)
               from calls c2
               where c2.call_id = c.call_id and c2.log = 'Connect'
              );
```

You can add an additional filter to the outer query for a particular `call_id`.

Comment: Thank you this worked. I had to change ID to date though. For some reason it wouldn't run using the ID. Still works though.

Comment: @Dylan . . . Based on your sample data, `id` looks like a good choice, but it `date` should also work.